# how to execute JS after the page fully shown on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, renderer

I got a JS problem, I want to excute a JS function after the whole page shown,the struct of the page such as:

```
<iframe id="i_frame" src="xxx.jsp"></iframe>
```

and the JS included in the xx.jsp:

```
...
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="yy.js"></script>
</head>
```

yy.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i_fram = $(window.parent.document).find('[id="i_frame"]');
    $(i_fram).load(function() {
        alert('trigger!');
    });
});
```

this works well on PC(chrome), but on Iphone4s(IOS8.1, Safari), the alert trigger befor the page completely shown, even it alert befor the bottom-half of the page shown.I'd tried:"http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onpageshow", it still has this problem.

Is there something different between Safari's renderer and other browsers?

Comment: I found this caused by safari cache. when i choose "Disable Caches", everything goes well, but if i enable it, the alert always pop befor the page shown.

Comment: I tried add:
"Cache-Control:no-cache
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache".in server side, and added "<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> 
<meta name="contentPath" content="/oa_app/">" in JSP,the js file included i append suffix such as '... src="yy.js"+Random()', it seemded no effect. some one metioned dynamicly chang the iframe id may force safari update the cache, as my test, it still not work as expected.any body who can help me, any idear!!